# How to conclude if a content is gziped or not in safari?

Tags: html, ajax, google-chrome, safari, gzip

If I compare the 'Content-Length' in chrome and safari, it shows same; but the 'Encoded' and 'Decoded' value is shown same in safari but varies in chrome. Also any other parameter I can use for comparing chrome and safari if gziped or not?

Please note, I am checking for an ajax response returning JSON object, and not any particular file as response.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect browser page and you will be able to see some tabs from that select network tab and refresh page, after that select any file which you want to check weather it is gzip or not. For selected file check response header which will show "Content-Encoding:gzip " if file is gziped.

[Check screen shot for details :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQKKt.png)

Comment: It does shows Content-Encoding:gzip in both chrome and safari, but as I have pointed in the question, The 'Compression' remains as 1x (encoded, decoded value is same) in Safari whereas there is a clear size difference for encoded and decoded values in chrome. So Content-Encoding:gzip is not helping to conclude.